# SOAP Response Error reading XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to invoke a SOAP webservice to validate VAT codes. The code works in Eclipse, but I'm getting below fault-string when invoking same code from JDeveloper 10.1.3 as that is where I need to integrate it with my rest of Oracle EBS code. I'm really stuck and looking for suggestions to get over the error.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader.</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

Code snippet:

```
package xxtest.vatvalidation.;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class VATValidationTest {
    
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService";
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        
          URL endpoint = new URL(null, url, new URLStreamHandler() { 
              protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException { 
                  URL clone = new URL(url.toString()); 
                  URLConnection connection = null; 
                  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(<proxy address>, <proxy port>)); 
                  connection = clone.openConnection(proxy); 
                  return connection; } });

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        
        String serverURI = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types";
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("urn", serverURI);
        
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("checkVat", "urn");
        soapBodyElem.addChildElement("countryCode", "urn").addTextNode("NL");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("vatNumber", "urn");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("NL999999999");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "#checkVat");
        
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage,  endpoint);
        //NodeList nList = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName("valid");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        soapConnection.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I could get it working using normal HTTP request following one of the answers on this site. Would still be interested to see if there is a better way of achieving this using javax.xml.soap package.

Working code using HTTP Request:

```
package xxtest.vatvalidation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

public class VATValidationHttp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String targetURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService";
        String urlParameters = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types\">"
                  +"<soapenv:Body>"
                     +"<urn:checkVat>"
                       +"<urn:countryCode>IE</urn:countryCode>"
                        +"<urn:vatNumber>IE9999999</urn:vatNumber>"
                     +"</urn:checkVat>"
                  +"</soapenv:Body>"
               +"</soapenv:Envelope>";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL(targetURL);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(<MY_PROXY_HOST>, <MY_PROXY_PORT>)); 
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                                          "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
                                          Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "ec.europa.eu");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.close();

            //Get Response  
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            System.out.println( response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```